# Need to multiply 3*3 matrixes in symbolic form in Python

Tags: python, robotics, inverse-kinematics

I need to matrix multiplication in symbolic form. I use this to determine inverse kinematics of a robot arm. So matrixes have trigonometric function and I need to multiply those matrixes as the symbolic view.
Any tips or reference is highly appreciate.

Comment: Check out `sympy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SymPy Python package for this.

[SymPy official Doc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html)

[TutorialsPoint tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sympy/index.htm)